# HTML <div> tag used for getting a scroll bar

Tags: html, css

i have a div section used for a scroll bar,but i am stuck with changing the width and height for the div section ,whatever i change no result.

```
<DIV class=scroll style=overflow-y:hidden;overflow-y:hidden> description</DIV>
```

in css
.scroll
{
}

Even without anythin inside "scroll" am getting scroll bar as i used overflow in DIV tag,but if i remove class=scroll in DIV scroll bar is not coming.i have used height width all changes but nothing happened pls guide me in right way

Comment: Offtopic:`div` should be lowercase (not a rule, but common practice), the value of `class`,`style` and other attributes should be wrapped in double quotes (This works, but again: common practice). And lastly, don't inline style, use your class (though it might be just for testing or this specific example).

Answer (score 4):

You can use this

```
<div style="overflow: scroll ;max-height: 250px; width: 50%;">
```

change property value as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

What doctype you are using? You should use html5 with your markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  ...
</html>
```

Comment: Almost downvoted this, but then I rememberred this specific case costing me a day to find the solution to.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline style and use `overflow: scroll` in CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/vqEkp/

The `hidden` `overflow-x/-y` tags explicitely tell the browser to always remove (hide) scrollbars.

If you want the scrollbars to only appear when they are needed, just leave the `overflow` tags out entirely, or set them to `auto`.

Alternatively, put the `overflow: scroll` bit in the inline style. Though generally you should use a stylesheet instead of inline CSS style whenever possible.

```
<DIV class="scroll" style="overflow:scroll"> description</DIV>
```

p.s. You should use quotes around attribute values.

Comment: I use this div as,            <table>                                                       <tr><td><table><tr><td>made it as header for main table</tr></td></table></tr></td>                                       <tr><td><div>my content</tr></td></div></table>

Comment: i have did the changes u said but still no change in size!

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle and mention the browser you tested in?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<div style="overflow: scroll;">your content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a specific element, you can create an ID.
Go to your css and do the following.

```
#element {
    width: ??px;
    height: ??px;
}
```

Go to your HTML and add "id="element".

```
 <DIV id="element" class=scroll style=overflow-y:hidden;overflow-y:hidden> description</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Permanent scrollbar

This will give a scrollbar to the element which will always be visible. If there is less content and no need for scroll, the scrollbar will still be there, just styled as disabled.

```
.scroll{
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100px;
}
```

### Scrollbar, only when needed

This will result in a scrollbar **when needed**, if there is less content en no need for scrolling, there will be no scrollbar. This might look better, and it doesn't take up any width.

```
.scroll{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100px;
}
```

### Doctype

The reason your inline coding is doing weird things might also be because of the wrong doctype, this should be defined. Common practice these days is `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`. You only have to place that at the very beginning of your html file, after that comes `<html>`

---

## Examples

```css
.example_auto{
    height: 75px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 24%; /*  just for demo */
    display: inline-block; /*  just for demo */
    vertical-align: top; /*  just for demo */
    background: #FFC; /*  just for demo */
}
.example_scroll{
    height: 75px;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 24%; /*  just for demo */
    display: inline-block; /*  just for demo */
    background: #FCF; /*  just for demo */
}
```

```html
<div class="example_auto">This is too little content to scroll.</div>
<div class="example_scroll">This is too little content to scroll.</div>

<div class="example_auto">This div has waaaaay more content en will need a scrollbar. This will look almost the same in both cases.</div>
<div class="example_scroll">This div has waaaaay more content en will need a scrollbar. This will look almost the same in both cases.</div>
```